# Error message "is not a valid path" when trying to load CSN file using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, oledbconnection

I want to have an ASP C# WebSite that loads a simple CSV File and present it in a GridView control (at least for a start).

I already have a piece of code that do almost all of the work, what i miss / unable to make it work is setting correctly the "Data Source".

The CSV file that I want to load is located on different server in the network (path is "\td47vc\public\Joe\ASP\Test").

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public DataSet GetCSVFile(string fileName)
{

    string pathName = "\\td47vc\\public\\Joe\\ASP\\Test";
    string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties=Text;");
    OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM " + file, excelConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelCommand);
    excelConnection.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    excelAdapter.Fill(ds);
    excelConnection.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

I get the following error:
'\td47vc\public\Joe\ASP\Test' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Thanks,

GorovDude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DataSet GetCSVFile(string fileName)
{

    string pathName = "\\\\td47vc\\public\\Joe\\ASP\\Test";
    string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties=Text;");
    OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM " + file, excelConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelCommand);
    excelConnection.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    excelAdapter.Fill(ds);
    excelConnection.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Actually I had a mistake in the code I wrote in the post, In the real solution I put the path like you suggested "\\\\td47vc\\public\\Joe\\ASP\\Test" but still the same errors come. I even used @ at the beginning of the string....

Answer (score 0):

That comes up mostly because of code access security or other permission issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx

This would anyways have performance bottleneck. It is highly recommended to have a local copy.